# Matching a text

Tags: python, regex

```
 import re
with open("anti-adblock-killer-filters.txt")as f:
contents=f.read()
pattern=re.compile(r"[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+##")

 matches=pattern.finditer(contents)

 count=sum(1 for match in matches)

print'There are total HTML Rule With Doamin =',count

pattern=re.compile(r'##')

matches=pattern.finditer(contents)

count3=sum(1 for match in matches)

result=count3-count

print'There are total HTML hiding rule without domain is  =',result

print'There are total HTML hiding rule with and without domain is  
=',result+count

pattern=re.compile(r'\W[||]')

matches=pattern.finditer(contents)

count2=sum(1 for match in matches)

print'There are total HTTP rule with Domain Anchor  =',count2
```

in this code the symbol "||" show domain achor 
domain tag is represented as  "domain="
i have to match for domain tag which is represented as in the file "domain=" so my first question is that whcih patten should i use to match http rule with domain anchor and domain tag  ?
2nd question is that which patteren will be used for matching Http rule without domain anchor and domain tag
same as 3rd question that 
if i want to match http rule with only domain tag 
then what will be the pattern ?

i am using anoconda python 3

your reponse will be highly apreciated.
thanks.

Comment: This looks more like a question about easylist than Python and regex. :-(

Comment:  which pattern should I use to match and count for Http rule without domain and anchor , I'm using python for matching and counting these rule

Comment: Please post your code as part of your question, not a link to a screenshot. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I fixed the formatting and indentation of your code--please check and make sure I don't mess anything up there.  Also, you're printing the reference to the function because you aren't actually calling the function.  Something like `print(get_rule_type(line))` is more what you are looking for.  However, line isn't actually a line... it's the entire file (all the lines as one string).  You probably want something more like [this](https://gist.github.com/jszakmeister/7e90e8da0ea1454e4d01a17023208b83) at the bottom of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
CSS="CSS"
COMMENT="COMMENT"
EXCEPTION="EXCEPTION"
FILTER="FILTER"

def is_comment(line):
    return line[0]=="!"

def is_css_rule(line):
    return '##' in line

def is_exception_rule(line):
    return '@' in line

def is_filter_rule(line):
    return not is_comment(line) and not is_css_rule(line)

def get_rule_type(line):
    if is_comment(line):
        return COMMENT
    elif is_css_rule(line):
        return CSS
    elif is_exception_rule(line):
        return EXCEPTION
    else:
        return FILTER

with open("abc.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        print('{:12s} {!r}'.format(get_rule_type(line), line))
```

Note: this is using Python 3.  Also, we're not making use of regular expressions, so there's no need to include the `re` package.